# Bug with iPhone data usage counter

Tags: iphone, ios, bug, tethering

I know that I can see the data usage of my iPhone 4(iOS 6.0.1) under: **Settings → General → Usage → Cellular, Usage** , but the counter has a bug - now it's showing over 16GB(for 2-3 hours tethering). Any Idea of the reason for this bug? If I use some app for counting the data usage, would it show the right usage?

Comment: My iPhone showed about 4Gt for 4 days' data usage while my operator showed about 1Gt for half month's data usage -- something odd: operator may not report data-usage on time or something wrong indeed with iPhone data usage counter. This is with iPhone 5 and iOS6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is probably just a bug in the data counting mechanism. You could download your carrier's app to test how much data you have really used.

Another thing to try would be updating your iPhone to 6.1.3. There are always some bugs fixed in each release, and maybe this is one of them.